# Index page coming blank after make a new installation in server in wordpress 3.3.1

Tags: php, wordpress

I make a new installation in my server and able to login with wp-admin.
I activate the theme from my wp-admin but when i visit my site it shows me as empty page , i am unable to find out the problem .

What is solutions for this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP error somewhere causing your WP to white screen.

Put WP into debug mode by adding this line to your `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

You should now see some sort of output on the page, update your question if you still can't work it out from this information.

Comment: this issue is solved ,there was some server error and it is now coming thanks, do you know magento

Answer (score 0):

If it's a brand-new server, make sure there aren't any index.html/index.htm files lurking in the root of the website.

Try just using the default 2011 theme. If it loads up fine, then you have a problem with your theme.

You might also check for whitespace before `<?php` and after `?>` in wp-config.php and your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: this issue is solved now ,there was some server issue so for it was not working on that time, but now its coming properly thanks. Do you know magento

Answer (score -1):

Put `php.ini` file in both front and back end. that will be work definitely..

hope it helps.. Let me know

Comment: I'm struggling to see how you came up with this random solution.

Comment: i had a problem with my site so i had included the php.ini file ,my site is working without of any problem

Comment: @Bharath Styen , this issue is solved now ,there was server issue and now the site is running properly thanks, Do you know magenot